# How to consume a webservice expecting "application/octet-stream" as Content Type and base64Binary as Type?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, webservice-client, datahandler

I have a webservice which expects a document in this format:

```
<xs:complexType name="document">
  <xs:sequence>    
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inhalt" ns1:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Eclipse asks for a DataHandler, so I tried passing a PDF file like so:

```
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(myDoc.getDocument(), "application/pdf");
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(dataSource, "application/octet-stream");
```

However, the webservice throws a persistence exception, signaling it can't work with the file I gave it. How else should I build the dataHandler?

(P.S. the sequence above contains 2 more String elements, which I have omitted here because they are not problematic

P.P.S. getDocument() returns byte[])

Answer (score 1):

It worked by leaving out the type for the dataHandler:

```
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(myDoc.getDocument(), "application/pdf");
DataHandler dataHandler = new DataHandler(dataSource);
```